# integer to date conversion issue in SQL vs Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

i have date value in integer as 43251, while converting in MS Excel its showing 31-05-2018. while converting using below sql

```
select convert(datetime,convert(int, 43251))
```

its showing 02-06-2018. why this difference in conversion from microsoft?

Comment: you have to add days to 1900-01-01, it's what SQL uses

Comment: @user3127554 . . . Not quite.  You should read my answer.

Comment: Be aware that your question is *not* about **SQL**, but about **SQL Server**. I've corrected the tag for you. In SQL an integer, such as 43251 is just a number. If you want to work with dates in SQL, then use the appropriate data type. SQL Server is a database program that allows for certain integer / date conversions, but this is product specific. Don't expect other products (such as Excel) to use the same formula.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i agree,but both are microsoft products. it should not differentiate the conversion. whether its right or wrong. it should work on both products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server uses a different date format.

I believe the correct conversion is:

```
select dateadd(day, 43251, '1899-12-30')
```

This is confusing. Excel treats `0` as `1900-00-00`, which means that 0 is 1899-12-31 and 1 is 1900-01-01.  That should suggest that the conversion is:

```
select dateadd(day, 43251, '1899-12-31')
```

However, that does not produce the correct date.  Why not?  Excel has incorrect leap year arithmetic.  So, it treats day 60 as 1900-02-29.  However, 1900 is not a leap year, so "60" should be 1900-03-01.

The rules for leap years are:

- Years that are divisible by 4
- Except years that are divisible by 100
- Except years that are divisible by 400

So, 2000 was a leap year, but 1900 and 2100 are not.

In other words, the dates are correct only for dates after 1900-03-01.

Comment: initial read, it was unclear that the 400 exception was an exception to the 100 rule.   I initially though what year is divisible by 400 but not 100?  why the need for the 400 exception.  your example helps clarify it, but the list is a tad confusing in my opinion.  Great answer otherwise though

Comment: @ForwardEd . . . I didn't write the rules for leap years.  That's just what they are.  Microsoft got it wrong in Excel.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: You have misunderstood. Forward Ed says, that "Expect years that are divisible by 400" sounds redundant when we already have "Except years that are divisible by 100". It is understood with your example, though.

Comment: I always love your inimitable insights and consummate comments Gordon!!  Please keep up the great work!!!!